# How do I write the query to get the exact result

Tags: mysql, php

I am confused about writing query in PHP, I want to:

```
1. SELECT RollNumber FROM student WHERE ProgramID= ?
2. SELECT DSID FROM datesheet WHERE CourseCode = ?
3. INSERT INTO result (DSID, RollNumber) VALUES (both queried above)
```

I've tried this using HTML dynamic tables but still unable to get the exact results that I want.

Also tried using this code that I've seen from a post of stackoverflow but nothing helped.

```
INSERT INTO result (DSID, RollNumber)
    VALUES (
        ( SELECT RollNumber FROM student WHERE ProgramID= ? ),
        ( SELECT DSID FROM datesheet WHERE CourseCode = ? )
           );
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: `SELECT DSID FROM datesheet WHERE DSID = ?` -- Huh?  If you have the DSID, why fetch it?

Comment: @RickJames my mistake here, actually that the code is:
`SELECT DSID FROM datesheet WHERE CourseCode = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I was able to solve my problem using this query:-

```
INSERT INTO result (DSID, RollNumber) 
     SELECT datesheet.DSID, student.RollNumber 
     FROM datesheet, student
     WHERE datesheet.CourseCode='Course Code Here'
     AND student.ProgramID='Class Here';
```

Comment: That looks like a "cross join".  Check the results; there may be far more rows than you expected.

Comment: No, I made is reconfirmed if my queries is inserting any additional/extra rows in new table or not? But after checking, I made sure that this query was fulfilling my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO result (DSIS, RollNumber)
    VALUES (
        ( SELECT RollNumber FROM student WHERE ProgramID= ? ),
        ( SELECT DSID FROM datesheet WHERE CourseCode = ? )
           );
```

A parenthesized `SELECT` can be used almost anywhere a value is needed.

(This solution, and Ahmed's, will have problems if there is more than one row from each table.)  Adding `LIMIT 1` to each subquery may suffice.

Comment: Actually the below code I posted, worked fine where it inserted 14 rows in new table. Perhaps, I will try your code executing in my PHP query too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good response and answer.

Comment: I have executed the code and following error was raised:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the

Comment: @AhmedRaza: Then you probably made an error in trying....  This will be hard to solve when you do not share what you actually tried!

Comment: @AhmedRaza - What does error message say after the word "near"?

Comment: I have tried using your query today using PHP but it game me error of more than 1 row. But as I used my own below posted query, worked perfectly.